# Implementing a chat application server for clients on Android/Windows Phone

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, flask, chat

I need to implement a group chat server which can support more than 50 users at a time.
The users will be only on mobile clients which include Android/Windows Phone.

Sending push notifs to the apps will not be difficult, as the server needs to do a basic curl request. So "polling" is not an issue.

My current skill set includes.

1. Flask
2. Google App Engine( I intent to use it or a web hosting
   server.)
3. Basic php

So from what I know, I can make http requests to the server with user specific information+chat msg.

The server processes this and sends a broadcast using push notifs to all the devices stored in database.The server identifies the device from the data in the http request.
How efficient will this be?

If this is not the correct approach, what all do I need learn(sockets programming?) and any framework which can make my work easier (it will help if it is also supported on GAE).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need XMPP messaging. It's support by App Engine but not in PHP : https://developers.google.com/appengine/features/

XMPP permit to send and receive chat messages.

Comment: So this is very similar to what I was thinking, making http post requests. Wont this be very slow for a real time chat application?